# EditorTemplate. MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I created EditorTemplate:

[image]

With code:

```
@model RentSite.Web.UI.Models.PhonesViewModel

<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.Number)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.From)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.To)
</div>
```

And i try to use it like this:

```
@model RentSite.Web.UI.Models.ContactsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddContact";
}

<h2>AddContact</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddContact","Contact",FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{    
    <input type="file" name="Image"/>
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Phoness )
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
}
```

ContactsViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace RentSite.Web.UI.Models
{
    public class ContactsViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PhonesViewModel> Phoness { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But i can't see any Editor at the page... Why??

Answer (score 2):

Your editor template model says its of type  PhonesViewModel but you are calling it with model.Phoness  which is `IEnumerable of PhoneViewModel`.

In your Editor template file, Change `@model RentSite.Web.UI.Models.PhonesViewModel`

to

```
@model IEnumerable<RentSite.Web.UI.Models.PhonesViewModel>
```

Comment: It doesn't exactly what I need. And, finally, it doesn't work.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: I want to be able to add one-or-more phones through this ContactsViewModel.

Comment: As per your code, this editor template will display 3 textboxes (number,from and to) to each entry in your IEnumerbale<PhoneViewModel>.Your question was about the content is not displaying. Are you sure you have items in the model.Phoness ? Put breakpoint in your controller action and see it before passing it to the view.

Comment: I had already understand my mistake. I'm trying to add new phone, but not to display. Can you give me any advice, how can I organize this? How can i add one-or-more phones?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763634/asp-net-mvc-3-dynamic-controls